# Назначить различный масштаб отображения картинки для константы JS

Tags: javascript

Я в JS мало что понимаю, но хотелось бы выяснить следующее. Есть константа

```
    const fishImages = [
        {src: "pictures/Karas_P.gif", pos: [330, 600]},
        {src: "pictures/Karas_L.gif", pos: [345, 670]},
        {src: "pictures/Karas_P.gif", pos: [330, 600]},
        {src: "pictures/Karas_L.gif", pos: [345, 670]},
    ];
```

в которой определены положения картинок. Возможно ли тут добавить различный масштаб их отображения?
Раз возможно указать разные координаты для отображения, то наверное можно и изменить масштаб отображения, наверное с помощью transform: scale(), но как это сделать у меня не получается.
Если возможно, то прошу специалистов подсказать как это сделать. Всем спасибо.

Comment: ""у меня не получается"" ---напишите в вопрос что делали, как пытались и что конкретно не получается.